# Extending c++ with a new keyword

Tags: c++

I want to extend c++ with some keywords, for example, "property", to add properties to a class/object (like Visual Studio extend C++ in the "managed" version).
  For a code example:

```
  class Example {
     public:
       [...]
       property int size {
             get: {
                   return __size;
                  }
             set: {
                   if( value > 0 )
                      __size = value;
                   else
                      throw new Exception("Invalid Size");
                   }
       };
};
```

Use:

```
   [...]
    int totalSize = example1.size + example2.size + example3.size;
    example1.size = 2 * example1.size;
```

What I want is to use a form of translator to translate a C++ "extended" source code to a "normal" source code, like QT MOC do, it parses a c++ source code and generated another c++ source code, with the QT "things" translated to bare c++.
  Of course, I will need to extend the translator (write code to it so it can understand what to do with the "property keyword").
  Do you know of a "translator" that I can use to do what I want?

Comment: Noop. I want to add other keywords beside "property". Also, how to expand, for example, the example1.size using only defines?

Comment: C++ is a hard enough language to parse (or even just tokenize) that this will be fairly difficult. Doing it to implement an idea as *bad* as `property` would be utterly insane. If you spend the time on it, I hope the other things you want do more to justify the work than `property` could hope to.

Comment: Well, this is why I want to use an existing translator/parser :-). As I wrote, "property" is only an example.

Comment: Clang has a [library based architecture](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#libraryarch) that could possibly be used to write C++ extensions (although not in the form of a `C++ ++ => C++` translator).

Answer (score 2):

Processing the header could be simply done using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). It is a Python-lib, which is a powerful but easy solution. I use it myself at work to parse a C-inspired definition file and produce valid C-code from it. For example, you could simply copy your header file but re-write the property definition, e.g. using something like this:

```
property  := Literal('property') id id Literal('{') [getter] [setter] 
             Literal('}') Literal(';')
getter    := Literal('get:') Literal('{') cpp_block Literal('}')
setter    := Literal('set:') Literal('{') cpp_block Literal('}')
id        := Word(alphas + '_', alphanums + '_')
cpp_block := ... don't know probably just match everything a la .*? ...
```

You could then attach actions to `setter` and `getter` to re-write the `cpp_block` into a method.

The difficulty starts with re-writing your C++ code. A simple parser will not know if `example1.size` is an access to a `struct` field (which should not be changed), a property-get or a property-set call.
So you need to know the type of `example1` but also if you access an lvalue or rvalue because `example1.size = 1` has to translate to `example1.set_size(1)` but `int a = example1.size` has to become `int a = example1.get_size()`.

So essentially, for the code translation you need the AST and the symbol table for looking up the type of the variable. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) has a C++ parser (see [here](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/cpp/CPP_parser.g)) but I'm not sure if it also generates the symbol table for you.

Comment: I will study it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at [boost::wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/wave/) and [LLVM](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2011-11/). Former is much easier and much more limited, but maybe it is the very thing you need.

Comment: I will study the 2, thanks. I saw [this video in Youtube - link](http://youtu.be/yuIOGfcOH0k), about using clang/LLVM to refactor c++, I'll play with them. Thanks.